# Understanding this Docker file - Where are the files being copied

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Being new to docker files. I am trying to understand how docker build is working here.
I currently have a folder that has two files in it. The folder is called `foo`
The structure of the folder is as follows. It has two files in it the first file is `main.go` and the other file next to it is `Dockerfile` as shown in the diagram below

```
Foo
|_main.go
|_go.mod
|_go.sum
|_Dockerfile
```

My Dockerfile currently looks like this and the command `docker build  -t ..` is called from inside the folder Foo.

```
FROM golang:1.18-alpine AS builder

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /app

COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

RUN go build -v -o my app
....
```

Now this is a fairly simple Dockerfile. Here is what I understand.

1- golang:1.18-alpine is the base image

2- In the container a folder called `app` will be created

3- `go.mod` and `go.sum` will be copied to `./` path of the container (probably home) of the container.

4- Run `go mod download` will be called from inside the `/app` folder correct ?

My question is basically for no. 4. `go mod download` called from inside `/app` folder ? If so how does that work because from my understanding is that the `/app` folder is so far empty ? When did the app folder get populated ? In the statement `COPY go.* ./` what path is `./` is that the home ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line `WORKDIR /app`, your current path will be set to `/app`. If the directory don't exist then it will be created beforehand.

Next `COPY go.* ./`, this matches all of files start with `go.` will be copied to `/app` directory in the docker container. So your docker `/app` should look like this :

```
/app
| go.mod
| go.sum
```

Again with `COPY . ./`, you are copying all files from current directory to `/app` directory of your docker container. It will replace already existing files in the contrainer. `/app` will look like this:

```
/app
| main.go
| go.mod
| go.sum
| Dockerfile
```

Last with `RUN go build -v -o myapp`, you are building the app using `go` and saving binary file `myapp`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that so are you saying that `./` in the above context means the current directory and the current dir has been set to `/app` by WORKDIR ? is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. `./` refereeing to `/app` inside the container.